# .gitattributes и окончания строк CRLF и LF

Tags: git

Есть репозиторий, требуется хранить файлы с текстами в формате с переводом строки **CRLF**.
Для этого в репо был добавлен файл **.gitattributes** вот с таким содержимым:

```
# all text files must be with CRLF EOLs. If not, they will be autoconverted into this state.
* text eol=crlf
```

При загрузке в репо и клонировании в новый каталог - всё как надо.
А вот если после этого выполнить **pull**, то при проверке изменений все файлы отображаются как изменённые.
При этом оконная утилита сравнения файлов из TortoiseGit показывает, что нет изменений. Но она умеет корректно показывать отличия в окончаниях строк, это я отдельно проверял.
А консольная утилита `git diff --`  показывает, что изменения почти во всех файлах во всех строках. Диалог TortoiseGit'а CheckForModifications показывает то же самое (количество lines added примерно равно количеству строк в файле).
Если удалить в рабочей копии файл .gitattributes, то количество "изменённых" файлов колоссально уменьшается.

Буду рад советам как исправить проблему, связанную с механизмом сравнения.

**UPD:**
Видимо проблема была в том, что добавление **.gitattributes** было сделано локально, т.е. изменения не запушены в удалённый репо. Т.е. теперь такой проблемы нет от слова **ВООБЩЕ**.

Comment: К сожалению TortoiseGit не умеет полноценно работать с атрибутами.

Answer (score 1):

Тот бардак с переводами строк, что у вас есть сейчас, это стандарт использования гита на винде (в рабочей папке CRLF, в репе - LF).

Если любите сравнивать файлы не в отдельной гуёвой программе, а прямо в консоли, вызывайте

```
git diff --ignore-cr-at-eol
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Бардак был ДО использования .gitattributes, с ним всё наладилось.